# FileOverflow when I create a new gemfile in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile, gemspecs

```
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\myproject> bundle package
...
...
...
Updating files in vendor/cache
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Updating files in vendor/cache

C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\myproject> gem build myproject.gemspec
```

> WARNING:  licenses is empty
>   WARNING:  no email specified
>   WARNING:  no homepage specified
>   WARNING:  description and summary are identical
>   **ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::TarWriter::FileOverflow)
>       You tried to feed more data than fits in the file.**

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're using such an old version of ruby? `v2.5.1` is the current latest. Support for `v1.9.x` was dropped years ago.

Comment: what files are you trying to add in your `gemspec`? Chaces are your error is here https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_551/lib/rubygems/builder.rb#L90

Comment: @TomLord thank you for your support, but I need to use this version in my project...

Comment: @engineersmnky I just want to create a new gem...

Comment: Right so please post your gemspec

Comment: @engineersmnky                                                                                    # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'XXX'
  s.version     = 'X.X.X'
  s.authors     = 'XXX
  s.description = 'XXX'
  s.summary     = 'XXX'
  s.email       = ''
  s.homepage    = ''

  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY

  s.files = Dir['*','*/**','*/**/**']
end